# Writing over writing when including a pdf

Tags: graphics, pdfpages

I'm writing a document on which to include a pdf that contains a table of description. This is the code I have used:

```
\begin{table}[!h]
\caption{Use Cases Description}
\begin{center}
\includepdf[pages={1}]{chapter3/description.pdf}
\end{center}
\label{description}
\end{table}
```

the problem is that I'm getting the table included from the pdf written over the previously written text, such as mentioned in the photo below. Also, I'm not getting the caption that I've made. What should I do?

[image: latex problem]

Comment: Includepdf is **not** for images, it is for full pages. Use `\includegraphics`. Includepdf does not make sense inside a float as it can never be as large as a full page.

Comment: And BTW welcome. The error you make is sadly a common one. Also dot use center to center inside floats. Replace `\begin{center} ` with `\centering` and remove `\end{center} `

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.